# Unit testing a method that uses (dynamic) using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dynamic, moq

I have the below method:

```
public void Enqueue(ICommand itemToQueue)
{
    if (itemToQueue == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("itemToQueue");
    }

    // Using the dynamic keywork to ensure the type passed in to the generic
    // method is the implementation type; not the interface.
    QueueStorage.AddToQueue((dynamic)itemToQueue);
}
```

With QueueStorage being a dependency that implements IQueueStorage.  I wish to unit test it but the (dynamic) keyword seems to be blocking Moq from binding correctly to it.  The keyword is used to correctly assign the concrete class type rather than ICommand interface type when it is added to the queue.

The unit test looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void Enqueue_ItemGiven_AddToQueueCalledOnQueueStorage()
{
    int timesAddToQueueCalled = 0;

    var dummyQueueStorage = new Mock<IQueueStorage>();
    var testCommand = new TestCommand();

    var queueManager = new AzureCommandQueueManager();

    dummyQueueStorage
        .Setup(x => x.AddToQueue(It.IsAny<TestCommand>()))
        .Callback(() => timesAddToQueueCalled++);

    queueManager.QueueStorage = dummyQueueStorage.Object;

    queueManager.Enqueue(testCommand);

    Assert.AreEqual(1, timesAddToQueueCalled);
}
```

Whilst test command is a blank implementation of ICommand:

```
private class TestCommand : ICommand
{
}

public interface ICommand
{
}
```

The `timesAddedToQueuCalled` is not being incremented.  I've tried using `It.IsAny<ICommand>` and `(testCommand)` to no avail.  It looks like the Callback method is not being executed.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: IQueueStorage code:

```
public interface IQueueStorage
{
    void AddToQueue<T>(T item) where T : class;

    T ReadFromQueue<T>() where T : class;
}
```

Comment: I fail to see whu you need the `dynamic` at all.  Why does it matter whether the type of the parameter of `AddToQueue()` is an interface or not?  The actual type cannot be the interface anyway

Comment: Code you provided works fine. Do you have several overloaded AddToQueue methods in IQueueStorage?

Comment: @Attila I am using Azure queue storage; if you are using XMLSerializer alongside a generic method it needs to know what it's serializing to the queue.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Single `AddToQueue` method in IQueueStorage.  I'll add the AddToQueue signature to the question

Comment: @Click-Rex are you using `It.IsAny<TestCommand>()`? Check maybe there something like `It.IsAny<ICommand>()`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky just tried it with the same result; I think it's something to do with the generic nature of the AddToQueue method combined with the (dynamic) keyword; maybe the .Setup Moq method can't bind correctly?

Comment: @Click-Rex it works fine with generics, just verified that. Make sure you provided same code as you have in your project

Comment: @lazyberezovsky this is the exact code from the project; maybe there is a difference in Moq version; I'm using 4.0.10827.0

Comment: @Click-Rex nope, same Moq version, the latest one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code which works without problems:

```
public class AzureCommandQueueManager
{
    public void Enqueue(ICommand itemToQueue)
    {
        if (itemToQueue == null)            
            throw new ArgumentNullException("itemToQueue");

        QueueStorage.AddToQueue((dynamic)itemToQueue);
    }

    public IQueueStorage QueueStorage { get; set; }
}

public interface IQueueStorage
{
    void AddToQueue<T>(T command) where T : class;        
}

public class TestCommand : ICommand  {}

public interface ICommand {}
```

And test method:

```
[Test]
public void Enqueue_ItemGiven_AddToQueueCalledOnQueueStorage()
{
    int timesAddToQueueCalled = 0;

    var dummyQueueStorage = new Mock<IQueueStorage>();
    var testCommand = new TestCommand();

    var queueManager = new AzureCommandQueueManager();

    dummyQueueStorage
        .Setup(x => x.AddToQueue(It.IsAny<TestCommand>()))
        .Callback(() => timesAddToQueueCalled++);

    queueManager.QueueStorage = dummyQueueStorage.Object;

    queueManager.Enqueue(testCommand);

    Assert.AreEqual(1, timesAddToQueueCalled);
}
```

The only difference I see - you have `private` modifier of `TestCommand` class. Btw if it is private, how do you access that class from your tests?

Comment: The class is embedded inside the Test class

Comment: My god; it was the `private` modifier; making it `public` means the `AzureCommandQueueManager` can read it. Thank you for the help!